# What temperature is considered bad for my processor?

Tags: intel, cpu, temperature

I am using the unity Temperature sensor and I have an Intel® Core™2 CPU 4400. If you need more info I would be happy to include more details about my PC that could help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case Temperature is the maximum temperature allowed at the processor Integrated Heat Spreader (IHS).  And according to Intel, your CPU has a L2=61.4°C, M0=73.3°C.  See [Package Specifications](http://ark.intel.com/products/29753/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-E4400-2M-Cache-2_00-GHz-800-MHz-FSB).

Answer (score 1):

Modern Intel CPUs have upper temperature limits of 100 C with a hardware shutdown at 105 C.